# Docker-compose scale command creates random ports for new containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ports

Currently docker-compose scale command creates random ports for the new containers.

Is there a way to specify a port for the new containers?

Answer (score 3):

In your `docker-compose.yml`,

```
postgres:
  image: postgres:9.5
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
```

it will bind to `5432`, however, note that you can't have more than one instance on the same node for obvious reason.

To use multiple instances on one node you can use dynamic ports like this

```
postgres:
  image: postgres:9.5
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  ports:
    - 5432+:5432
```

Thus allowing the `scale=4` to create 4 instances published on `5432`, `5433`, `5434`, `5435`, but all routing to their internal ports.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas 
I believe this option is in docker 1.15+above and docker-compose v3 but i am using docker 1.12 and compose v2 (which this solution doesnt work). Is there any alternative.

Comment: This isn't really released yet(compose 1.17.0). However, they are planning to implement adding port range which seems as a better option but not sure if it's implemented yet.

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1241

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/722