# Docker-Compose: Expose range ports to host while scale containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using a docker-compose file and I need to scale specific containers by using the command

```
docker-compose scale taskcontainer=3
```

Unfortunately this is not possible due to the fact that I need to expose a specific port from all internal containers and I need a port range on host to make it happen. For example consider the following snippet

```
  taskcontainer:
    image: custom-container
    ports:
      - "9251:9249"
```

when I scale to 3 containers I need to export port 9249 from internal containers to 3 ports on host e.g. 9251-9253 (to avoid port clash on host) and I need that functionality dynamically because I do not know in advance how many containers will be used for scaling.

Is there a way to achieve that functionality?

Comment: Youe can specify something like "9251+:9249", or in lower version of docker-compose you can specify "9251-9260:9249" 
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768685/docker-compose-scale-command-creates-random-ports-for-new-containers