# How to configure port mapping for replicated containers in Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The goal is to run two containers of `publisher-app`. One container should be mapped to port 8080 on the host machine, and the other on 8081. Here is the `docker-compose`:

```yaml
  publisher_app:
    ports:
      - "8080-8081:8080"
    environment:
      server.port: 8080
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2
```

Two containers are created, but as I understand, both ports are assigned to the first one, and the second one produces this error: `Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8081: bind: address already in use`.

Here is the output of `docker ps -a`:

```
6c7067b4ebee   spring-boot-rest-kafka_publisher_app   "java -jar /app.jar"     33 seconds ago   Up 28 seconds              0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->8080/tcp   spring-boot-rest-kafka_publisher_app_2
70828ba8f370   spring-boot-rest-kafka_publisher_app   "java -jar /app.jar"     33 seconds ago   Created                                                                     spring-boot-rest-kafka_publisher_app_1
```

Docker engine version: 20.10.11

Docker compose version: 2.2.1

How to handle this case? Your help will be very appreciated.

Here is the source code: https://github.com/aleksei17/springboot-rest-kafka-mysql/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: what `docker ps -a` output shows?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli, added the output to the question

Comment: I tried to mimic your configuration and it works for me - https://gist.github.com/the-toster/76506934cb9e2e858d3fe363d8d9cda1, can you provide minimum example that fails for you?

Comment: It's a bug with docker-compose v2: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8530

Comment: @Aleksei can you check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49768896/5459640) works for you? this is an older implementation

Comment: @Anton, tried to run your example and it did not work. What docker version do you have? I have docker engine 20.10.11, docker compose version 2.2.1, and it's running on Intel Mac.

Comment: @Petesh, that indeed can be the reason. I have docker compose version 2.2.1

Comment: @NoamYizraeli, no it did not work, I got an error: `error decoding 'Ports': Invalid hostPort: 8080+`

Comment: @Aleksei try reverting to the stable version listed in docker's docs (I think currently it's 1.29.2 check [this link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)

Comment: @NoamYizraeli, I tried `docker-compose disable-v2`, this set docker compose version to `1.29.2`. Then I set port range like `"8080-8081:8080"`. Still did not work.

Comment: There was an issue in docker-compose v2 https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8530 
I think this is already fixed by docker-compose version v2.5.0 as it worked for me running your settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tried locally on Windows 10 and failed similarly, both with v2 and with v2 disabled.

It seems like a [compose issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7188)

when tried on arch: `amd64` fedora based linux distro with package manager installed docker and manually installing docker-compose `1.29.2` ([using the official guide for linux](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose-on-linux-systems)) **worked**:

compose file:

```
version : "3"
services:
  web:
    image: "nginx:latest"
    ports:
      - "8000-8020:80"
```

docker command:

```
docker-compose up --scale web=5
```

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                                   NAMES
b304d397b2cd   nginx:latest                              "/docker-entrypoint.…"   14 seconds ago   Up 7 seconds              0.0.0.0:8004->80/tcp, :::8004->80/tcp   testdir_web_4
a8c6f177a6e6   nginx:latest                              "/docker-entrypoint.…"   14 seconds ago   Up 7 seconds              0.0.0.0:8003->80/tcp, :::8003->80/tcp   testdir_web_3
b1abe53e7d7d   nginx:latest                              "/docker-entrypoint.…"   14 seconds ago   Up 8 seconds              0.0.0.0:8002->80/tcp, :::8002->80/tcp   testdir_web_2
ead91e9df671   nginx:latest                              "/docker-entrypoint.…"   14 seconds ago   Up 9 seconds              0.0.0.0:8001->80/tcp, :::8001->80/tcp   testdir_web_5
65ffd6a87715   nginx:latest                              "/docker-entrypoint.…"   24 seconds ago   Up 21 seconds             0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp, :::8000->80/tcp   testdir_web_1
```